# How to DROP a table from a specific SCHEMA in POSTGRES?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, database-schema, drop-table

I am using Heroku, and Postgres database.

I somehow have same table but in two different schemas, first one in public, second one in a custom schema I called mySchema. I need to drop the table which is in Public schema.

Should I put the schema name before the table and it will work ?
`heroku pg:psql -c "DROP TABLE public.myTable;" -a myAppInHeroku`

Comment: Just replace `public` with `myschema`

Comment: But I need to drop the one in public, and keep the one in mySchema

Comment: Then the code you have, will do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I just did `heroku pg:psql -c "DROP TABLE public.myTable;" -a myAppInHeroku` and it removed the table from the public schema as I wanted.